# Android static Application.getInstance()

Tags: android

Could you help me with this situation. We are using a static instance of a class that extends Application in android.

```
public class MyClass extends Application {

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        if(mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = new MyClass();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public MyObject getMyObject() {
        return myObject;   
    }
}
```

MyObject should be accessible everywhere and we are accessing like . `MyClass.getInstance().getMyObject()`. It works most of the time. Sometimes in Service method this instance returns null. But when we access this object immediately in the same control within an Activity on UserLeaveHint() or onPause() when we try to print this object the same instance returns with a valid object and not null. Could someone please help us out?

Answer (score 29):

You should instantiate the singleton class with an other way (and not simply create a new object), in OnCreate method which is called when application starts:

```
public class MyClass extends Application {

    // Singleton instance
    private static MyClass sInstance = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Setup singleton instance
        sInstance = this;
    }

    // Getter to access Singleton instance
    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return sInstance ; 
    }
}
```

And be sure to link this class to *application tag in Manifest.xml*

```
...
<application
    android:name="package.MyClass"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
</application>
....
```

Comment: That probably has to be sInstance rather than mInstance if it's static

Answer (score 0):

Try use in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".YourService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't (or at least *SHOULD NOT*) create an instance of `Application` explicitly. Every 'app' has a single instance of `Application` which is created by the OS when you start the app. This happens whether you choose to extend `Application` or not (what do you think the `Context` returned by `getApplicationContext()` references?).

If you want your `Application` to main a static object then it's as simple as this...

```
public class MyClass extends Application {

    private MyObject mObject = null;

    public static MyObject getMyObject() {
        if (mObject == null)
            mObject = new MyObject;
        return mObject;
    }
}
```

From anywhere in your code you can then just use...

```
MyClass.getMyObject();
```

...to get an instance of your object.

Comment: mObject will not be accessible from the static method getMyObject.

Comment: be careful with getApplicationContext() and assuming it returns a reference to your application class (MyClass in this case).  That method is overridden by some manufacturers so code like ((MyClass)getApplicationContext()).getMyObject() will result in a class cast exception.