# Why not show data when use Dagger2 on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, picasso

In my application i want use **Dagger2** and i want show just one image from server and for show image i used **Picasso**.
I write below codes, but after run application not show me any image into `imageview`!
For android i use **Kotlin** language.

**Application class :**

```
class App : Application() {

    var component: AppComponent? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //Init dagger component
        component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().modulePicasso(ModulePicasso(this)).build()
    }

    fun getAppComponent(): AppComponent? {
        return component
    }
}
```

**Activity class :**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        App().getAppComponent()?.getPicasso()?.load("https://cdn01.zoomit.ir/2017/6/5f0e97c1-9eb7-4176-aa02-35252489ede8.jpg")
            ?.into(imageView)
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: you should use an injection pattern to inject and dependency into your activity class. and as far as Picasso is concerned i donth think you need to use injection for this unless and until you are doing some middleware work in Picasso methods. just do a Picasso.get().
for kotlin dependency injection I would suggest having a look at kodein or koin. its simpler and would get your work done to much extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you are creating a new instance of you application class, eg. `App()` and then calling `getAppComponent()` which for sure returns `null`, as you should **not** construct the application instance yourself, but instead access a static property referencing it.

To fix it, you need to add a static property (`instance`) to the `App` class and get the `AppComponent` using that property.

Comment: Thanks dear, i think this too. can you help me and send to me code?

Comment: Basically, you define `lateinit var instance: App` inside a companion object in the `App` class. Then, in `onCreate`, you initialize: `instance = this`. You can have a look at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29295509/4971561) to get an inspiration.

Comment: Well, instead of calling `App().appComponent`, you call `App.instance.appComponent`